# htaccess: How to redirect from old domain to new with folder condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was just wondering if it is possible to redirect from old domain to new if condition is matched. here is what I am trying to achieve.

> http://olddomain.com/downloads/anyfile.anyext ->
>   http://newdomain.com/downloads/anyfile.anyext

OR

> http://olddomain.com/downloads/anysubfolder/anyfile.anyext ->
>   http://newdomain.com/downloads/anysubfolder/anyfile.anyext

Here is what I have tried so far but not working and I'm not sure if this is right:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/downloads/
RewriteRule "^/downloads/(.+)" http://www.newdomain.com/downloads/$1 [R,L]
```

The reason I'm trying to achieve this is because we recently moved our downloads folder to our new server so both domains are actually pointing to a different server so I still need the olddomain.com working. Is it possible..

Thank you Stackoverflow and thank you in advance for all your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect from `olddomain/downloads/foobar` to `newdomain/downloads/foobar`
you can use the following Redirect :

```
Redirect /downloads/ http://newdomain.com/downloads/
```

Comment: and the conditions?

Comment: You really don't need RewriteConditions as your destination domain is on a diffrent webserver.